# php strtotime "last monday" if today is monday?

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

I want to use `strtotime("last Monday")`.

The thing is, if today IS MONDAY, what does it return? 
It seems to be returning the date for the monday of last week. How can I make it return today's date in that case?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

> How can I make it return today's date in that case?

pseudocode:

```
if (today == monday)
    return today;
else
    return strtotime(...);
```

Btw, this trick also could work:

```
strtotime('last monday', strtotime('tomorrow'));
```

Comment: @nute: well, I've checked all possible cases: any middle-week day, and edges: sunday & monday. All returns expected result. I think there are no problems, except of semantics ;-)

Comment: Also see the [answer by dotjon](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8981753/216084) to this question only for a more elegant solution.

Comment: @Gopal Aggarwal: I remember there are some edge cases when `this` in `strtotime` points to now what you want. Cannot provide any particular example though

Comment: @zerkms Sorry, but I am not getting your point. Kindly elaborate.

Comment: @Gopal Aggarwal: from what I remember, there are cases when `this` may refer to a former week, not to this

Comment: @zerkms Okay. Well, I am putting my faith in core PHP's abilities :) And if there are certain edge-cases, I am hopeful they will be found and resolved in coming versions.

Comment: @GopalAggarwal: your faith is misplaced :) "this week" does not work for Sundays.  Example, today is Sunday 2015-03-01, but "Sunday this week" will return 2015-03-08. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798026/php-week-starts-on-monday-but-monday-this-week-on-a-sunday-gets-monday-next and https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63740&thanks=6

Comment: @Sarthaz Thanks for the heads-up and the links. I hope you do not mean what you say. If PHP as a language and a community cannot (or cannot hope to in a reasonable time) better its core functions once a bug has been reproduced, then maybe we should listen to 'PHP sucks' and move elsewhere.

Comment: If you're calling this repeatedly, try `strtotime('last monday', time() + 86400);`. Does exactly the same thing but saves a call to the expensive strtotime function.

Answer (score 149):

If you read the manual, there is an great example that describes exactly what you want to do https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php#datetime.formats.relative

```
strtotime('Monday this week');
```

**Update:** There appears to be a *bug* introduced in newer versions of PHP where `this week` returns the wrong week when ran on Sundays. You can vote on the bug here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63740

**Update 2:** As of May 18th 2016, this has been fixed in PHP 5.6.22, PHP 7.0.7 and PHP 7.1-dev (and hopefully remains fixed in subsequent releases) as seen here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63740#1463570467

Comment: I don't get why the other answer was accepted. For further readers, this solution is better, it does exactly what is being asked.

Comment: Very useful for e.g. Drupal and Views where you can only input a date string.

Comment: This is clever piece of code imho, but it may be not selected because it lacks 'generalization', which can be important for people coming from Google.

Comment: @EralpB, there's nothing clever about it. It's core PHP, widely supported, bug free, and semantically correct! :)

Comment: @Jose Garrido. Perhaps because this answer was given 2 years later?

Comment: If the day is Sunday, this will return the date of Monday of next week, rather than the Monday of the current week.

Comment: @chap, turns out ```this week``` returns a Monday if run on a Sunday. It's a ridiculous bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63740

Comment: 5.6.23, 7.0.8 Weeks always start on monday. Formerly, sunday would also be considered to start a week.

Comment: Good luck relying on "this week" outside the US of A.

Answer (score 5):

If today is Monday, strtotime("last Monday") will return a date 7 days in the past. Why don't you just check if today is Monday and if yes, return today's date and if not, return last week?

That would be a foolproof way of doing this.

```
if (date('N', time()) == 1) return date('Y-m-d');
else return date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last Monday'));
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: just curious, what if it was `Now, 8th 23:59:59.999` in your `if()` clause and when interpreter reach `return` clause - it is already `Now, 9th` (tuesday)? ;-)

Comment: Ha, I was trying to keep it short. Personally I would declare today and last Monday first and then make the comparisons to avoid the race condition. I'm a bigger fan of your working back from tomorrow method.

Comment: yeah, race condition is the most weird bug to detect. Sorry if my comment looks rude.

Comment: Not at all. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 3):

As it was correctly outlined in the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4150501/4354249), this trick works, but also had [caveats](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63740) prior to `PHP 5.6.22`, `PHP 7.0.7` and `PHP 7.1-dev`:

```
strtotime('last monday', strtotime('tomorrow'));

// or this one, which is shorter, but was buggy:
strtotime('Monday this week');
```

To those, who prefer the "Jedy-way", to work with objects of [the `DateTime` class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#class.datetime), the solution is next:

```
(new \DateTime())->modify('tomorrow')->modify('previous monday')->format('Y-m-d');
```

or even shorter notation:

```
\DateTime('Monday this week')
```

---

Be carefull, because if you do the same on SQL, you don't need to have any of these tricks in [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) with addition of "tomorrow". Here's how the solution will look:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY) as last_monday;
```

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but I thought I would post up this answer (which is actually from a different but related question). It handles the scenario in the question:

```
function last_monday($date) {
    if (!is_numeric($date))
        $date = strtotime($date);
    if (date('w', $date) == 1)
        return $date;
    else
        return strtotime(
            'last monday',
             $date
        );
}

echo date('m/d/y', last_monday('8/14/2012')); // 8/13/2012 (tuesday gives us the previous monday)
echo date('m/d/y', last_monday('8/13/2012')); // 8/13/2012 (monday throws back that day)
echo date('m/d/y', last_monday('8/12/2012')); // 8/06/2012 (sunday goes to previous week)
```

try it: http://codepad.org/rDAI4Scr

... or a variation that has sunday return the following day (monday) rather than the previous week, simply add a line:

```
 elseif (date('w', $date) == 0)
    return strtotime(
        'next monday',
         $date
    );
```

try it: http://codepad.org/S2NhrU2Z

You can pass it a timestamp or a string, you'll get back a timestamp

**Documentation**

- `strtotime` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php
- `date` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

Depending on exactly what you're using it for, this may be useful. Since one second's ambiguity is OK for my requirements, I use:

```
date( 'Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime( 'last sunday' ))
```

to get midnight on the most recent Monday (or today if today IS Monday).

Answer (score 0):

My aproach:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
function givedate($weekday, $time) {
$now = time();
$last = strtotime("$weekday this week $time");
$next = strtotime("next $weekday $time");
    if($now > $last) {
        $date = date("d.m.Y - H:i",$next);
    }
    else {
        $date = date("d.m.Y - H:i",$last);
    }
    return $date;
}

echo givedate('Wednesday', '00:52');
```

Or monthly

```
    function givedate_monthly($weekday, $time) {
    $now = time();
    $last = strtotime("first $weekday of this month $time");
    $next = strtotime("first $weekday of next month $time");
        if($now > $last) {
            $date = date("d.m.Y - H:i",$next);
        }
        else {
            $date = date("d.m.Y - H:i",$last);
        }
        return $date;
}

echo givedate_monthly('Wednesday', '01:50');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$monday = strtotime('Monday last week');
$sunday = strtotime('+6 days', $monday);
```