# Calculating a week's dates list starting from a given date

Tags: php, date

I need to get a given week's dates list when a one date of that week and the starting day is given. Starting day may be Monday, Sunday etc.

Comment: Don't know why you got a -1, this isn't a terribly bad question so here's a +1.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get all Work Days in a Week for a given date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202576/get-all-work-days-in-a-week-for-a-given-date)

Comment: @Endophage - It wasn't me, but it was probably downvoted because it shows no research effort or code.  Questions on StackOverflow are expected to "show what you have tried".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way that I think works, not sure it's the most efficient way. $weekStart should be set to the day you consider the first of the week (0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday etc) and $date is the input date.

```
$weekStart = 0;
$date = '2011-06-1';

$timestamp = strtotime($date);

$dayOfWeek = date('N', $timestamp);

$startDate = mktime(0,0,0, date('n', $timestamp), date('j', $timestamp) - $dayOfWeek + $weekStart, date('Y', $timestamp));
$endDate = mktime(0,0,0, date('n', $timestamp), date('j', $timestamp) - $dayOfWeek + 6 + $weekStart, date('Y', $timestamp));

echo 'Week runs from ' . date('Y-m-d', $startDate) . ' to ' . date('Y-m-d', $endDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace $dayOfWeek = date('N', $timestamp); with $dayOfWeek = date('w', $timestamp); because if using a Sunday it was returning wrong week dates.
Tested using $date = '2013-07-28'.

```
$weekStart = 0;
$date = '2011-06-1';

$timestamp = strtotime($date);

$dayOfWeek = date('w', $timestamp);

$startDate = mktime(0,0,0, date('n', $timestamp), date('j', $timestamp) - $dayOfWeek + $weekStart, date('Y', $timestamp));
$endDate = mktime(0,0,0, date('n', $timestamp), date('j', $timestamp) - $dayOfWeek + 6 + $weekStart, date('Y', $timestamp));

echo 'Week runs from ' . date('Y-m-d', $startDate) . ' to ' . date('Y-m-d', $endDate);
```