# how to find the beginning of any week in php?

Tags: php, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get first day of week in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897727/get-first-day-of-week-in-php)

i have this script that give's me the beginning and the end of the current week:

```
$begweek = (date('l') == 'Monday')?date('Y-m-d'):date('Y-m-d',strtotime('last monday'));
echo $begweek;

echo "<br>";
$endweek = (date('l') == 'Sunday')?date('Y-m-d'):date('Y-m-d',strtotime('Sunday'));
echo $endweek;
```

what i need is a way to find the beginning and the end of any week if i pass a random date, like `$date="2011-11-15"`;

an ideas on what i need to modify in the current script to accommodate this variable?

thanks

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202576/get-all-work-days-in-a-week-for-a-given-date/6202709#6202709 - example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/82ADWj

Comment: lots of duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=first+day+of+week+php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date function takes a second parameters.

**THE CODE**

```
function blah($date){

    $begweek = (date('l', strtotime($date)) == 'Monday')?date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date)):date('Y-m-d',strtotime('last monday', strtotime($date)));
    echo $begweek;

    echo "<br>";
    $endweek = (date('l', strtotime($date)) == 'Sunday')?date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date)):date('Y-m-d',strtotime('Sunday', strtotime($date)));
    echo $endweek;

}

blah("2011-11-15");
```

**THE OUTPUT**

2011-11-14
2011-11-20

Answer (score 0):

[date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) takes a second parameter which is a timestamp to get the date of

use [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to get the timestamp.

```
date( 'l', strtotime( $date ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 'last monday', but just pass [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) the timestamp of the random date as it's second parameter.

Comment: "last monday" will return the monday before $date when $date is a monday