# PHP function to loop business days between two posted dates

Tags: php, date, loops

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Print Y-m-d list of business dates between two dates from MySQL using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904033/print-y-m-d-list-of-business-dates-between-two-dates-from-mysql-using-php)

I'm new to these kind of PHP programming so bear with me.

I want users to be able to post two dates, a startdate and a enddate and from these dates calculate the business dates (exclude Saturday and Sunday) and insert these to `MySQL`

For example if I have this form...

```
<form action='update.php' method='post'>
  <input type='text' name='start_date'>
  <input type='text' name='end_date'>
  <input type='submit' name='submit'>
</form>
```

**update.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

   $start_date = $_POST['start_date']; //Let's say this is 2012-10-01
   $send_date = $_POST['end_date']; //Let's say this is 2012-10-10

}
```

Now I would like to loop through the dates and create a MySQL query that would run like this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_dates (date_value) VALUES ('2012-10-01');
INSERT INTO tbl_dates (date_value) VALUES ('2012-10-02');
INSERT INTO tbl_dates (date_value) VALUES ('2012-10-03');
INSERT INTO tbl_dates (date_value) VALUES ('2012-10-04');
INSERT INTO tbl_dates (date_value) VALUES ('2012-10-05');
INSERT INTO tbl_dates (date_value) VALUES ('2012-10-08');
INSERT INTO tbl_dates (date_value) VALUES ('2012-10-09');
INSERT INTO tbl_dates (date_value) VALUES ('2012-10-10');
```

I know this is probably not a good solution but it's how I need it.

How do I create the loop?

Comment: +1 for having a clear explanation

Comment: I don't recommend doing so , it's not a standard database design. It will provide lots of data duplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$startDate = $start_date;
$endDate = $send_date;

// Convert to UNIX timestamps
$currentTime = strtotime($startDate);
$endTime = strtotime($endDate);

// Loop until we reach the last day
$result = array();
while ($currentTime <= $endTime) {
  if (date('N', $currentTime) < 6) {
    $result[] = date('Y-m-d', $currentTime);
  }
  $currentTime = strtotime('+1 day', $currentTime);
}

// start insertion
foreach($result as $value)
{
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_dates (date_value) VALUES '".$value."'");
}
```

Source : [Print Y-m-d list of business dates between two dates from MySQL using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904033/print-y-m-d-list-of-business-dates-between-two-dates-from-mysql-using-php)

Omg! I just realized that it's a thread started by you. You already have your answer

Comment: do not copy code from other questions on StackOverflow please. If an answer exists you can copy code from, it means the question you want to paste it to is a duplicate.

Comment: The section I copied was a part of the solution. I also included the next part to complete the solution. And that is the reason why I also mentioned the source in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`date('N', $timestamp)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to get the number of the day of the week. You can then check if this day matches Your requirements.

P.S. `date('N')` was introduced in PHP 5.1.0

Comment: You can use `w` if you are worried about PHP version.

Comment: @SalmanA: Thanks for noticing. Didn't see that in the list of formats.

Answer (score 0):

Code in your flavor on the basis of your `PHP` tag only ->

```
<?php

$_POST['start_date'] = '2012-10-01';
$_POST['end_date'] = '2012-10-10';

$start = explode('-',$_POST['start_date']);
$end   = explode('-',$_POST['end_date']);
$i = (int)$start[2];
for($i; $i<$end[2]; $i++)
{
$i = sprintf('%02d', $i);
echo "INSERT INTO tbl_dates (date_value) VALUES ('2012-10-$i')";
echo "<br />";
}

?>
```

**Output**

```
INSERT INTO tbl_dates (date_value) VALUES ('2012-10-01')
INSERT INTO tbl_dates (date_value) VALUES ('2012-10-02')
INSERT INTO tbl_dates (date_value) VALUES ('2012-10-03')
INSERT INTO tbl_dates (date_value) VALUES ('2012-10-04')
INSERT INTO tbl_dates (date_value) VALUES ('2012-10-05')
INSERT INTO tbl_dates (date_value) VALUES ('2012-10-06')
INSERT INTO tbl_dates (date_value) VALUES ('2012-10-07')
INSERT INTO tbl_dates (date_value) VALUES ('2012-10-08')
INSERT INTO tbl_dates (date_value) VALUES ('2012-10-09')
```

Comment: This code does not exclude saturday and sunday but thank's anyway.

Comment: @David aah my bad i just mised that point & thought it to be a loop only problem