# get date from DateTime Object

Tags: php, arrays

After more than an hour struggling and trying I'd like to ask it here.

Trying to make something with weeks etc. in php I got from you site this:
[Get all Work Days in a Week for a given date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202576/get-all-work-days-in-a-week-for-a-given-date)

Nice and will work for me fine.

But ... I can't get, trying and trying,  the data out of this part:  `[date] => 2013-08-12 00:00:00`

```
Array
(
    [0] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2013-08-12 00:00:00
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => Europe/Amsterdam
        )
```

How to get that date out of the array ?
Please help me out, thanks in advance for the help  !

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DateTime::format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

```
$dateTime = new DateTime('2013-08-12 00:00:00');
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d'); // produces 2013-08-12
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$firstMondayThisWeek= new DateTime('2013-08-12');
$firstMondayThisWeek->modify('tomorrow');
$firstMondayThisWeek->modify('last Monday');

$nextFiveWeekDays = new DatePeriod(
    $firstMondayThisWeek,
    DateInterval::createFromDateString('+1 weekdays'),
    4
);

$dateTimes = iterator_to_array($nextFiveWeekDays);
foreach ($dateTimes as $dateTime) {
    echo $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```