# PHP: Help on this code for getting all the days in a week of a month

Tags: php, date

My code needs to get the weeks along with its first and last day in a month, my code is working but in some months, the first and last day of the last week becomes the combination of the first day of next month and the last day of the current month. Start of week is sunday.

**Input** is any date in `Y-m-d format e.g.(2014-01-05)`, *the day won't matter because it will be converted to the first day of that month anyway*.

This is the **output** when the month is january which has a **problem**:

```
2014-01-01 2014-01-04
2014-01-05 2014-01-11
2014-01-12 2014-01-18
2014-01-19 2014-01-25
2014-01-26 2014-01-31
2014-02-02 2014-01-31 // here lies the problem
```

This is the **output** when the month is February which is **correct**:

```
2014-02-01 2014-02-01
2014-02-02 2014-02-08
2014-02-09 2014-02-15
2014-02-16 2014-02-22
2014-02-23 2014-02-28
```

The functions I'm using:

```
function getWeeks($from) {
        $array = array();

        $from = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($from));

        $start_date = date('Y-m-01', strtotime($from));
        $end_date = date('Y-m-t', strtotime($from));
        $end_date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($end_date." + 6 days"));
        $week_array = array();
        for($date = $start_date; $date < $end_date1; $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date. ' + 7 days')))
        {
            $getarray = getWeekDates($date, $start_date, $end_date);
            $week_array[] = $getarray;
        }

        return $week_array;
    }

function getWeekDates($date, $start_date, $end_date)
    {
        $week =  date('W', strtotime($date));
        $year =  date('Y', strtotime($date));
        $from = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("{$year}-W{$week}+3"));

        if($from < $start_date) $from = $start_date;

        $to = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("{$year}-W{$week}-6"));
        if($to > $end_date) $to = $end_date;

        $obj = new stdClass();
        $obj->from = $from;
        $obj->to   = $to;

        return $obj;
    }
```

I looked at [Get all Work Days in a Week for a given date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202576/get-all-work-days-in-a-week-for-a-given-date/6202709#6202709) but it does not help answer my question, because it uses a different implementation. I'd like to use my own implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the getWeeks function:

```
for($date = $start_date; $date < $end_date1; $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date. ' + 7 days')))
{
    $getarray = getWeekDates($date, $start_date, $end_date);
    if($getarray) $week_array[] = $getarray; // change it to this
}
```

on the getWeekDates function:

```
$from = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("{$year}-W{$week}+3"));

if($from > $end-date) return null; // Add this
if($from < $start_date) $from = $start_date;

$to = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("{$year}-W{$week}-6"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I've roughed together a script which may help, you will need to put it into a class like you had before or perhaps it will help find the issue with your code. Either way hope it helps.

PS I hate working with dates! :)

```
        $dateToday = date('Y-m');
        $monthToday = date('m');
        $yearToday = date('y');

        $totalDaysInMonth = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $monthToday, $yearToday);
        $dateOfFirstSunday = date('l Y-m-d', strtotime($dateToday . " first Sunday"));
        $dayOfFirstSunday = date('j', strtotime($dateToday . " first Sunday"));
        for($n = 1; $n < $dayOfFirstSunday; $n++){
            echo date('l Y-m-d', strtotime($dateToday . '-' . $n)) . "<br>";
        }

        echo $dateOfFirstSunday . "<br>";

        for($n = $dayOfFirstSunday + 7; $n <= $totalDaysInMonth; $n +=7){
            $lastN = $n;
            echo date('l Y-m-d', strtotime($yearToday . '-' . $monthToday . '-' . $n)) . "<br>";   
        }
        for($n = $lastN+1; $n <= $totalDaysInMonth; $n++){
            echo date('l Y-m-d', strtotime($dateToday . '-' . $n)) . "<br>";
        }
```